# How to use PDF.js with ashx pdf handler

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I have a url to a pdf which totaly works. but i don't know how to use here:
path:Whatever/DownloadFile.ashx?dDocName={1}&IsPrimary=0&Inline=1

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    PDFJS.disableWorker = true;
    PDFJS.getDocument('path').then(function getmyPDF(pdf) {

        pdf.getPage(1).then(function getPage(page) {
            var scale = 1;
            var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

            var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.height = viewport.height;
            canvas.width = viewport.width;

            page.render({ canvasContext: context, viewport: viewport });
        });
    });
});
```

It should render the file into a canvas but its blank.

Comment: can you provide fiddle?

Comment: use `PDFJS.workerSrc = 'path_to/pdf.worker.js';` instead of `PDFJS.disableWorker = true;`